# How do I remove the shadow on header for React Native on Android, React Navigation v6?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The shadow looks like this.

[image: Example of Shadow on Android]

I've tried using

```
headerStyle: {
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
    }
```

but according to this link
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator#options
in React Navigation v6, the only property supported in headerStyle is backgroundColor only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For react-navigation v6 you can use [headerShadowVisible](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headershadowvisible) to hide or show the header's shadow.

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShadowVisible: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component {NotificationsScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```